# Override a link within a <p> tag

Tags: css

I am building out a page in our CMS and wants to override the color of the "Search" link on default and hover states. But my override script won't work.

```css
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .item a.register:link { color:#000000; }
  .item a.register:hover { color: #4278f5; } 
}
```

```html
<section class="component ">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="item">
        <h4>Hospital</h4>
        <p></p>
        <p><a href="https://www.google.com/">Search</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You can't have nested styling in pure CSS. It only works in CSS preprocessors like SASS and LESS. Is that CSS or SASS?

Comment: @MahdiAryayi that isn't nested styling, just media query.

Answer (score 0):

Without the pseudo selectors, your selectors are `.item a.register` and `.item a.register`. It means `a` element with the class `.register`, inside an element with `.item` class.

In your example `.register` is not applied to your `a` so they are not selected, it should work if you remove this condition or add the missing class.

SCSS (without `.register`):

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {
 .item a{
    &:link {
      color:#000000;
    }
    &:hover { 
      color: #4278f5;
    }
 }
}
```

CSS without `.register` :

```css
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .item a:link {
    color:#000000;
  }
  .item a:hover {
    color: #4278f5;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="component ">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="item">
        <h4>Hospital</h4>
        <p></p>
        <p><a href="https://www.google.com/">Search</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS with `.register` :

```css
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .item a.register:link {
    color:#000000;
  }
  .item a.register:hover {
    color: #4278f5;
  } 
}
```

```html
<section class="component ">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="item">
        <h4>Hospital</h4>
        <p></p>
        <p><a class="register" href="https://www.google.com/">Search</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hey, are you able to provide me the updated override script? Thank you.